# Inserting a border below text in Html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am building a website in Html and CSS. Currently I have a small problem where I am struggling to place a border below text like in the image below. Here's my code in Html

```
<div class="Sectionheading">
     <h1>LegalPractice Area</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.Sectionheading{
    text-align:center;
}
h1{
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    position:relative;
}
h1:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 60px;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ff9700;
}
```

```html
<div class="Sectionheading">
     <h1>LegalPractice Area</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the horizontal row tag right after your h1 to get the output you are looking for:

```css
.Sectionheading{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="Sectionheading">
     <h1>LegalPractice Area</h1>
     <hr style="width:10%">
</div>
```

For reference check this page out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp